# Can I update my DBLP profile, or connect it to Google Scholar?

Tags: research-process

I find my Google Scholar profile to be more updated and accurate than DBLP. Is there any way I can update DBLP accordingly or connect it to Google Scholar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBLP has two FAQ entries that roughly correspond to your question:

- Correcting inaccurate entries: [you can submit error reports](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/How+can+I+correct+errors+in+dblp.html)
- Updating information (new entries): [you can't enter publications directly, but the DBLP team is open to suggestions](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/How+can+I+enter+my+publications+to+dblp.html)

The latter also describes how their indexing process works in general, which indirectely explains why it won't be possible to synchronize your Scholar profile with DBLP automatically, In essence, they consider a much more restricted set of sources than Google does.